# TCP Server unable to receive the data when send by GPRS Modem

Tags: java, tcp, serversocket, gprs

Following code works fine with java client, the server can able to receive the data correctly, but it is not works with GPRS client. GPRS Client using `AT` command in `Serial Terminal`(Docklight) to send the data to java server.

```
public class Tcpserver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String clientSentence;
    String capitalizedSentence;

    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(90);
    while(true)
    {             
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("connected:" );
        System.out.println("message length: "+ connectionSocket.getInputStream().available());
        BufferedReader inFromClient =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
        capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
    }
}

}
```

Can anybody point the problem with this code or else in what way we have to get the data from GPRS Modem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code can only read one line per connection. You need to start a new thread per connection and have it handle all the I/O, in a loop of its own.

I'm also wondering whether the GPRS client is sending line terminators. You might be better off just reading and writing bytes:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

operating directly on input and output streams, with any buffer size > 1, say 1024 for a start. `count` is an `int.`

I don't see why you should need to capitalize anything either. If the server doesn't understand what the GPRS modem actually sends, someone needs to fix it so it does.